# Solving $y'' = -y \cdot (y')^2$ analytical

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$y'' = -y \cdot (y')^2$$

But I always have some trouble solving nonlinear ODE. I used wolfram alpha to check the solution but it used complex number and the $\text{erf}$ function and I'm not very used to work with it. Is that the only way of solving this analytical? If so, how Can I solve this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Wolfram Alpha's solution, set $v(y) = y'$. Then $$y'' = \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = v\frac{dv}{dy}$$ so the equation becomes $$vv' = -yv^2$$

Which means either $v = 0$ or $$v' = -yv \to \frac{1}{v}dv=-ydy$$

Which has solution $\ln(v) = -\frac{1}{2}y^2+c \to $ $$v = Ce^{-y^2/2}$$

Then the equation is $$y' = Ce^{-y^2/2} \to e^{y^2/2}dy=Cdx$$

which has the solution of $$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{erfi}\left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = c_1x + c_2$$

Or equivalently, $$y = \sqrt{2}\text{erfi}^{-1}\left(c_1x + c_2\right) = -i\sqrt{2}\text{erf}^{-1}\left(c_1x + c_2\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

This equation is separable,
$$
\frac{y''}{y'}=-yy'
$$
The resulting first-order equation might not as easy to integrate. And will possibly contain the inverse of the error function in its solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'' + y \, (y')^2=0$$

Switch variables to make
$$-\frac{x''}{[x']^3}+\frac y{[x']^2}=0\implies x''=y \,x'$$ Reduction of order $p=x'$ gives
$$p=c_1 e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}$$ Now, another integration
$$x+c_2=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} c_1 \text{erfi}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Do not try to get y(x).